# upgrade Appium from 1.4.8 to 1.5.0

Tags: macos, selenium, appium

Is it possible to upgrade straight from appium 1.4.8 to appium 1.5.0 or should i upgrade to the closest version?

Basically, on mac all i need to do is to type sudo npm install appium@1.5.0?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use *appium-version-manager* to deal with this :

```
$ npm install -g appium-version-manager
```

then install a specific version saying :

```
$ avm 1.5.0
```

Learn more about it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/appium-version-manager).

Comment: mkdir: /usr/local/avm/versions/1.5.2: Permission denied

  Error: sudo required

Comment: @Shay12345678 : the error says **sudo required**, try using sudo to run the command

Comment: it started to install but now i get a different error:

Comment: npm WARN ENOENT ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/avm/versions/1.5.2/package.json'

/usr/local/bin/avm: line 286: appium: command not found

Comment: Error: Cannot find module 'lodash._basetostring'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:

Comment: @Shay12345678 : that shall ideally go into some other thread I believe.

Comment: if i installed 1.5.2 why i still have the gui of 1.4.8?

Comment: @Shay12345678 : could you please check where did you install it

Comment: thanks for your help. i solved the issue by using: npm install -g grunt-cli
and after that npm install -g appium

Answer (score 0):

This will automatically install the latest version:

```
npm install -g appium # globally install appium
```